# for loop not working properly for dynamic data of array of array

Tags: arrays, loops, for-loop, dynamic, push

questionOptions[index] is ["Yes","No"]
links = [  {Value="No"},  {Value="Yes"},  {Value="No"}  ]

my static value for responseValues is [ [0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0 ] ]

```
for (let k = 0; k < links.length; k++){
    const optionName=questionOptions[index].find((option) => option === links[k].Value);
    if (optionName) {
        const optionIndex = questionOptions[index].indexOf(optionName);
        responseValues[optionIndex][k] = responseValues[optionIndex][k] + 1;
     }
}
```

when I provide static Vaue in array of "responseValues" for loop is working.. but when i fetch data dynamically, last line in for loop giving me value like [[1,0,0], [1,0,0] at end of 1st loop (k=0). Actual value should be [[0,0,0], [1,0,0]]...and at end of all k=2 loop, final answer should be [[0,1,0],[1,0,1]].

dynamic array is something like this where childQuestions.length =3 and questionOptions[index].length = 2

```
let childOptions = [];
let responseValues = [];
for (let i = 0; i < childQuestions.length; i++){
    childOptions.push(0);
}
for (let t = 0; t < questionOptions[index].length; t++{
    responseValues.push(childOptions)
}
```